# change cell background of excel file in datatable excel export for columns having desired class

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables

How to change the cell background color of an excel file in data table excel export for columns having desired class let's say i have a class name = .error

Basically i need to highlight the desired cells such as changing the backgrounf color as red in the excel file that fails validation. But struggling as don't know how to do it..

for example i took this code..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [{
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                customize: function(xlsx) {
                    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
 
                // Loop over the cells in column `C`
                $('row c[r^="C"]', sheet).each( function () {
                    // Get the value
                    if ( $('is t', this).text() == 'New York' ) {
                        $(this).attr( 's', '20' );
                    }
                });
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="table">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr class="bg-dark text-white">
                                                    <th>S.No</th>
                                                    <th>CID</th>
                                                    <th>Material Name</th>
                                                    <th>Category</th>
                                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                                    <th>Unit</th>
                                                    <th>Location</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>1</td>
                                                    <td>CID-001</td>  
                                                    <td>Material Name-1</td>
                                                    <td>Category-1</td>
                                                    <td>6000</td>
                                                    <td>KG</td>
                                                    <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="error">2</td>
                                                    <td>CID-002</td>  
                                                    <td>New York</td>
                                                    <td>Category-2</td>
                                                    <td>6000</td>
                                                    <td>KG</td>
                                                    <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>3</td>
                                                    <td>CID-003</td>  
                                                    <td>Material Name-3</td>
                                                    <td>Category-3</td>
                                                    <td>6000</td>
                                                    <td>KG</td>
                                                    <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

here i can know that we are looping over each cell of sheet1 and checking if the cell contains the text "New York" so, similarly i want to know how to change the background color of any cell that has a class named .error

Answer (score 1):

[UPADTE]
Because the cell' classname here is not being exported to the spreadsheet, we have to parse the sheet' content and compare by reference to cell indexes in the rendered table By using Datatables [cell()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell()) in the loop.

We can add styling attributes to the rendered XML spreadsheet by following [excelHtml5 Guidelines](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5), where Normal text with red background would be referenced by `$(this).attr('s', '10');` as a predefined styling attribute value equal to 10.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
columns=$("table").find("th").length; //Count Columns
var table=$('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [{
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        customize: function( xlsx ) {

var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];

//console.log(sheet);
var row = 0;

$('row', sheet).each(function(x) {
//The xml file' data begins after Raw 2. Usually The first is the for the Document' title
//And the Second for the headers 
if (x > 2) {
    for(var i=0; i<columns; i++) {
    //to avoid using the ":eq() Selector" being deprecated in the latest jQuery versions
        if ($(table.cell(row, i).node()).hasClass('error')) {
        //C is the cell tag like (td) and S is the styling attribute
          $('row:nth-child('+(x)+') c', sheet).eq(i).attr('s', '10');                 
        } 
    }

    row++;
}

});

}
    }]
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script> 
    <table id="example" class="table">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr class="bg-dark text-white">
                                                    <th>S.No</th>
                                                    <th>CID</th>
                                                    <th>Material Name</th>
                                                    <th>Category</th>
                                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                                    <th>Unit</th>
                                                    <th>Location</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>1</td>
                                                    <td>CID-001</td>  
                                                    <td>Material Name-1</td>
                                                    <td>Category-1</td>
                                                    <td>6000</td>
                                                    <td>KG</td>
                                                    <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="error">2</td>
                                                    <td>CID-002</td>  
                                                    <td>New York</td>
                                                    <td>Category-2</td>
                                                    <td>6000</td>
                                                    <td>KG</td>
                                                    <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>3</td>
                                                    <td>CID-003</td>  
                                                    <td>Material Name-3</td>
                                                    <td>Category-3</td>
                                                    <td>6000</td>
                                                    <td>KG</td>
                                                    <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

Unfortunately we can't output the Spreadsheet Xml in StackOverflow snippet editor. So this is a link to the [Raw Xml format](https://pastebin.com/tHiMmCSy). That could help as a reference to tag names being used by this library.

Comment: will this reflect this in excel too ?

Comment: If you can update your question with a snippet or an example fiddle, I'd be able to test it with you.

Comment: I check your update with my code above..but doesnt seem like its working.. or am i wrong anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! I found the solution...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var output_table = $('#example').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [{
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                customize: function(xlsx) {
                    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                                        var row = 0;
                                        $('row', sheet).each(function (x) {
                                            if (x > 1) {
                                                for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                                                    if ($(output_table.cell(':eq(' + row + ')', i).node()).hasClass('error')) {
                                                        $('row:nth-child(' + (x + 1) + ') c', sheet).eq(i).attr('s', '10');
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                row++;
                                            }
                                        });
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="table">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr class="bg-dark text-white">
                                                    <th>S.No</th>
                                                    <th>CID</th>
                                                    <th>Material Name</th>
                                                    <th>Category</th>
                                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                                    <th>Unit</th>
                                                    <th>Location</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>1</td>
                                                    <td>CID-001</td>  
                                                    <td>Material Name-1</td>
                                                    <td>Category-1</td>
                                                    <td>6000</td>
                                                    <td>KG</td>
                                                    <td class="error">Abu Dhabi 1</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="error">2</td>
                                                    <td>CID-002</td>  
                                                    <td class="error">New York</td>
                                                    <td>Category-2</td>
                                                    <td>6000</td>
                                                    <td>KG</td>
                                                    <td>Abu Dhabi 2</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>3</td>
                                                    <td class="error">CID-003</td>  
                                                    <td>Material Name-3</td>
                                                    <td>Category-3</td>
                                                    <td>6000</td>
                                                    <td>KG</td>
                                                    <td class="error">Abu Dhabi 3</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

From this link -->   https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/55877/how-to-set-excel-exports-cells-background-colors-by-table-cell-class

Comment: I was busy the whole day but I just found the same link you mentioned here :) And it's weird that it doesn't figure in their docs ! At first, I answered as if it was a regular jQuery selection that was it would never work this way. I'll update my answer with an explanation may be that could help somebody else.